# open new popup window and return value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a new popup window, insert values into database, after that return one value to current window. After I open a new popup window and click return, it returns the value but when I click on submit and return it after that, the value doesn't get returned. I think that's because the new window gets refreshed by the submit button. That's why it doesn't return the value.

Main Page

```
<form></form>

<form>
<input name="maparea" size="2" type="TEXT">
<input onclick='targetitem = document.forms[1].maparea; dataitem = window.open("popup.php", "dataitem", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes"); dataitem.targetitem = targetitem' value="Get Value" type="button">
</form>
```

Popoup window

```
<script>
   function select_item(item){
      targetitem.value = item;
      top.close();
      return false;
   }
</script>

<form  action="" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" />
   <input type="button" name="re" value="Return" onclick='return select_item("3")' />
</form>
```

Any solution for that?
I want to submit what I want first after that return the value

Comment: change `top.close();` to `window.close();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the popup, hook an onclick event on your submit button so it executes before the submit.
Then in the onclick handler do:

```
window.opener['dataitem'] = <your return value>;
```

Then after the submit, your parent window will have that value, and you can access it like this:

```
var somevariable = window['dataitem'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function setColor(color){ if (opener && !opener.closed){ opener.document.theForm.theField.value = color; opener.focus(); } window.close(); } ... <td width="30" bgcolor="#FFFF00" onclick="setColor(this.bgColor)">&nbsp;</td>
Read more at http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=61319#gkH9pd6gdgvxYqQZ.99
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

1. Open your popup.
2. In the popup: submit the form *via AJAX* (to avoid a page refresh).
3. In the popup: In the success handler for your AJAX call, grab the desired value, pass it back using `window.opener`, then close the popup.